# Making WebApi method asynchronous - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following action in my Web Api controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/geom")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddRef([FromBody]Peticion empObj)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=xx;database=xx;User Id=xx;Password=xx"))
    {
        string query = "UPDATE [dbo].[tmp_parcelas] SET[geom] = geometry::STGeomFromText('" + empObj.geom + "',25830) WHERE[idparcela] = " + empObj.id + ";";
        using (SqlCommand querySaveStaff = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            querySaveStaff.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

It receives a lot of requests in a very short period of time (like 60 in 1 second or so), so I guess it is necessary to make the method asynchronous.

> How can I make the controller action run asynchronously?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make it truly asynchronous, you need to do few things:

1. Change return type of the method to `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`
2. Mark it with `async` keyword so you can asynchronously wait (`await`) on other tasks inside of it
3. Use asynchronous version of methods for opening database connection and query execution

So, after refactoring, method should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/geom")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddRef([FromBody]Peticion empObj)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection-string"))
    {
        string query = "query";
        using (SqlCommand querySaveStaff = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            querySaveStaff.Connection = con;
            await con.OpenAsync();
            await querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            con.Close(); // in this case not needed will be closed when disposed
        }
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```